# How to add Mvc4 Model items to jquery array in mvc4?

Tags: jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using one mode and structure is as below.

```
public class detailsbyclientIdviewModel
    {
        public int upldId { get; set; }
        public IPagedList<detailsbyClientId> detailsbyclientId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my controller code.

```
List<detailsbyClientId> detailsbyclient = objBAL.detailsbyclient(cId);
            IPagedList<detailsbyClientId> pagedLog = detailsbyclient.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
            detailsbyclientIdviewModel model;
            model = new detailsbyclientIdviewModel()
            {
                detailsbyclientId = pagedLog
            };
```

For example detailsbyclientId have 8 items in it. For example i can retrieve and display each item as below.

```
@foreach (var group in Model.detailsbyclientId)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @group.clientName </td>
           </tr>
        }
```

Same as above, I have one property detailsbyclientId.upldId.
for example if my detailsbyclientId has 5 items then my detailsbyclientId.upldId has 5 items in it. I want to put all those 5 detailsbyclientId.upldId  to jquery array. Is this possible to push model items to jquery array. I have tried something like this but no luck.
var listArray = new Array();

```
@foreach(var data in Model.detailsbyclientId)
    {
        listArray.push(data.upld_Id);
    }
```

Comment: You can create your array using `var ids = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.detailsbyclientId.Select(x => x.upld_Id)))` But the query should really be on the server, not on the client.

Comment: I implemented. now ids holding required values. May i know which query should really be on the server?

Comment: Your view model should have a property (say) `IEnumerable<int> Ids`, and in the GET method - `model = new detailsbyclientIdviewModel() { Ids = pagedLog.Select(x => x.upld_Id), detailsbyclientId = pagedLog }` and then in the view `var ids = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Ids))`

Comment: Yes i understood. but i wrote query inside script and it also works fine. Anyhow i implemented as you said by writing query in server side. thanks a lot. Can you put answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix razor (server side code) and javascript (client side code) like that  (the `foreach` runs on the server before its sent to the client and `listArray` is a javascript variable which does not exist at that point. You can use

```
var listArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.detailsbyclientId.Select(x => x.upld_Id)))
```

although the query should be in the controller, not the view. Add a property to your view model

```
public IEnumerable<int> Ids { get; set; }
```

and modify the controller code to

```
List<detailsbyClientId> detailsbyclient = objBAL.detailsbyclient(cId);
IPagedList<detailsbyClientId> pagedLog = detailsbyclient.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
detailsbyclientIdviewModel model = new detailsbyclientIdviewModel()
{
    Ids = pagedLog.Select(x => x.upld_Id), 
    detailsbyclientId = pagedLog
};
```

and in the view

```
var listArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Ids)))
```